# Cannot get exact values after parsing JSON from GCM message

Tags: php, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

This is my PHP code implementing GCM push notifications,below is the data i am sending

```
$fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
            'data'              => array("message" => array( "id" => $id , "date" => $date , "performance" => $performance , "attendance" => $attendance ))
            );
```

This is the android code from which i am getting the values

```
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
```

This is the json parser class

```
json = new JSONObject("{message}");
stime = json.getString("performance");
name.setText(stime);

String slecturename = json.getString("attendance");
deal.setText(slecturename);

String sroom = json.getString("date");
valid.setText(sroom);

String sfaculty = json.getString("id");
address.setText(sfaculty);
```

In the message field i got the value as

```
 {"id":"1","performance":"Poor","attendance":"Present","date":"2014-02-02"}
```

But i was not able to parse it with exact id and get the value,i dont know where i am doing it wrong.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
json = new JSONObject(message);
```

Instead of

```
json = new JSONObject("{message}");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 json = new JSONObject("{message}");
```

to

```
 json = new JSONObject(message);
```

coz you have `String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");`

Your rest of the parsing looks fine